# For what $p$ is $\frac{1}{(x(1+\ln(x)^2))^p}$ Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I'm trying to use the fact that given $f:[a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ Riemann integrable for every closed interval $[c,d]\subset [a,\infty)$, then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if, and only if, $\int_a^\infty|f(x)| \, dx$ exists.

In particular, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x(1+\ln(x)^2)}$ is $p$-Lebesgue integrable if $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^p(1+\ln(x)^2)^p} \, dx<\infty $. Here using the fact that $f>0$.

But I can't solve this Riemann integral.

Comment: A typography experiment: Do the following look different from each other? $\displaystyle x²$ versus $\displaystyle x^2$.  I changed the former form to the latter in the question. It is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, they do. Thanks for editing.

Comment: If $a>0$ then $x+\ln x\sim x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich here a=0.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. I.e., $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^p(x+\ln{x}^2)^p}\,dx$ $\leq$ $\sqrt{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2p}}\,dx}$ $\sqrt{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+\ln{x}^2)^{2p}}\,dx}$

Comment: Ok. Split the integral into $\int_0^{1/2}$ and $\int_{1/2}^\infty$. For the second integral use the fact that $x+\ln x\sim x$; that should let you figure when _that_ part converges. Now for the integral from $0$ to $1/2$ think about it; for $x$ in that range $x+\ln x$ is approximately what?

Comment: Of course $\ln x$ was a typo for $\ln(x)^2$...

Comment: It's not true that $1+\ln(x)^2\sim 1$. Well, it's true near $x=1$. So you can use that for $\int_{1/2}^2$. And now think about approximately how large $1+\ln(x)^2$ is for $x>2$ and how large it is for $0<x<1/2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I sent an e-mail to my professor and he corrected it to $f(x):=\frac{1}{x(1+\ln(x)^2)}$

Comment: Before trying to answer, it is better for the OP to settle for a definitive form of his question. Judging by the comments, I see lots of $\ln x^2$ whereas the question mentions $(\ln x)^2$. The comments speak about $x+\ln x$, the question about $x+x \ln x$. So, which one is the final version? Questions with so many problems usually get downvoted, so...

Comment: @AlexM. It's $(\ln{x})^2$. Sorry.

Comment: The final version is just like in the question. I had some problems with latex in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function produces infinities in both endpoints of the interval. The usual approach is to split the integral using some well-behaved intermediate point, say $x=1$. Therefore, $\int \limits _0 ^\infty = \int \limits _0 ^1 + \int \limits _1 ^\infty$.

Concerning the first one, make the change of variable $x = \Bbb e ^{-t}$, obtaining $\int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {\Bbb e ^{(p-1)t}} {(1+t^2)^p} \Bbb d t$. This clearly converges if $p \le 1$. If $p>1$, the function is essentially unbounded towards $\infty$, so no chance of being integrable.

Concerning the second one, the same change of variable will produce $\int \limits _{-\infty} ^0 \frac {\Bbb e ^{(p-1)t}} {(1+t^2)^p} \Bbb d t$ which, with exactly the same argument as above, converges only for $p \ge 1$.

To conclude, when $p>1$, the first part diverges and the second one converges, so the whole integral diverges. When $p<1$ it diverges again. The only case of convergence is $p=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the inequality $\frac{x}{x+1} < \log (1+x) < x$ for ll $x>-1$ and $x \ne 0$. Let $x=u-1$ then the inequality becomes $\frac{u-1}{u} < \log (u) < u-1$ for all $u>0$. Thus, $\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2}< (\ln x)^2<(x-1)^2$ so that $1+\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2}<1+ (\ln x)^2<1+(x-1)^2$ which implies that  $\frac{1}{1+\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2}}>\frac{1}{1+ (\ln x)^2}>\frac{1}{1+(x-1)^2}$.

Thus, $\frac{x^{2p}}{(x^2+(x-1)^2)^p}>\frac{1}{(1+ (\ln x)^2)^p}>\frac{1}{(1+(x-1)^2)^p}$.

Alos, since $x>0$ then, $$\frac{1}{x^p(1+ (\ln x)^2)^p}<\frac{x^{p}}{(x^2+(x-1)^2)^p}.$$

Using Maple 12, I tried to integrate $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{x^{p}}{(x^2+(x-1)^2)^p}dx}$ I get that the integral converges when $p\ge2$, diverges when $p<2$.